# Query AppInsights on a Custom Property

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have the following being logged. Is there a way to query AppInsights on the prop_CorrelationId in where clause?  I've tried the following, but neither return the information.  Notice 1st one is going against "requests" and 2nd is going against "traces":

```
let numberOfDaysAgo = ago(6d);
requests
| where timestamp > numberOfDaysAgo and customDimensions.prop_CorrelationId == "568abba7-6601-4159-a3b1-ef27b2437473"

let numberOfDaysAgo = ago(6d);
traces
| where timestamp > numberOfDaysAgo and customDimensions.prop_CorrelationId == "568abba7-6601-4159-a3b1-ef27b2437473"
```

[image: Customer Properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you're incorrectly using `_` instead of `__`(it's double `_`) in `prop_CorrelationId`.

So please use `prop__CorrelationId` instead of `prop_CorrelationId` in your query.

For example:

```
let numberOfDaysAgo = ago(6d);
requests
| where timestamp > numberOfDaysAgo and customDimensions.prop__CorrelationId == "568abba7-6601-4159-a3b1-ef27b2437473"
```